# PyDev reports import error for installed modules in site-packages but does run the code

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, pydev

I've just started using PyDev for Python 2.7 on MacOS 10.8.3.  The only problem I have is that for the line...

```
from PIL import Image
```

It reports "Unresolved import: Image".  However, I can run the code from the command line and from within PyDev and the import works within the PyDev console.

I have both of...

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL
```

...in the Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter-Python->Libraries section.  I have run Apply, redone the whole thing, and tried a few other things that others have reported for problems that look similar.  Does anyone know of any definitive way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found two different ways to fix this:

1. Go to Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreter - Python -> Forced Builtins, click "New..." and enter "PIL" (without the quotes). Click OK twice and restart Eclipse.
2. Change your import statement to "import Image" instead of "from PIL import Image".